# How to to render a webform (or any configurable form) in a node edit form?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a weird use case, where I was looking to perform the following:

- In a node edit form, allow a user to entity reference a collection of webforms
- When a user selects an appropriate webform from the entity reference autocomplete, render that form in the current node edit form
- User fills out fields in these webforms then proceeds to save the node.
- On node save, the webform submit data is stored in a particular field in the node (perhaps in json format).

Is this even possible with webforms, or do any other form modules exist that support this use case?

Comment: This seems counterproductive to what Webform (basically) provides. What is the use case?

Comment: We're basically trying to compose a page using reusable components. For example, a page may contain a hero with 3 fields (image, title, subtitle), followed by a 3 col layout which may contain the fields -title, paragraph. The idea was to use a schema form to define these fields and reference the forms we needed in the node form via entity references. The user can add values to these webform fields and build a page with this. We could also use content types, but that would drastically increase the number of content types we use. Idea was derived from here - http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/

Comment: You might want to look at Paragraphs module first.

Comment: I completely agree with @Kevin, just adding this module https://www.drupal.org/project/classy_paragraphs which might help in the front end part of the solution as well. " Classy paragraphs ships a new field type "Class list" which allows an editor to apply a selected class to paragraphs via a drop-down list."

Comment: Great, thanks all, I really appreciate it! I'll play with the paragraphs module and let you know if it covers my needs!

Comment: The paragraphs module looks like it should do the job for me. Question on performance though, would adding at least 20 paragraph bundles/types with 3-5 fields in them cause severe performance issues?

Comment: It will result in a good amount of configuration files, but the main bottleneck is how many paragraphs you have on a single node and how nested they are. We have seen sites that have paragraphs fields on paragraph types resulting in 5+ layers. Then performance on saving and load can be an issue

Answer (score 0):

In this instance it sounds like the paragraphs module solves your problem. However to answer your original question...

I would use [entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform), not webform to do this.

Once you added all of your field to your entity form then you can use [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) to embed the child form.